# Uploading an image into a Web Service from an ImageView

Tags: swift, rest, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to upload an image taken by the device camera, or selected from the device Gallery, later present it at the screen with an ImageView, and at last upload it to a Rest API. I already have a default image stored in the Rest API and my App is already loading this image, but when I try to change the image I have issues.

This is my code after the Post API call, the data of my JSON:

```
let defaultServiceResponse = data["defaultServiceResponse"] as! NSDictionary
            self.idResponse = defaultServiceResponse["idResponse"] as! Int
            let loginModel = LoginModel()

            if self.idResponse == 0 {

                let userInfo = data["userInfo"] as! NSDictionary
                loginModel.imageProfileUrl = userInfo["imageProfileUrl"] as! String 
                let url = URL(string: loginModel.imageProfileUrl)
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                self.userImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

Then I have a second class where I'm trying to upload the image:

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePicked: UIImageView!

 @IBAction func openCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func openPhotoLibraryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imagePicked.image = image
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButt(sender: AnyObject) {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePicked.image!, 0.6)
        let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!, nil, nil, nil)

        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Wow",
                                message: "Your image has been saved to Photo Library!",
                                delegate: nil,
                                cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
```

When I tap the openCamara button and openLibrary button it does the correct function each time, but when I choose the photo (either from the Camera or the Gallery) it doesn't appear anything at the ImageView, and the error I receive is: "Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
"
And I'm not sending back the image into the Rest API because I haven't any idea of how can I do that.

Can somebody help me showing where is the error that is not letting me show the picture at the screen on the ImageView?

And if it's posible can somebody show me the best way to return that image into my Rest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zita Noriega Estrada
this code will remove your all errors.

```
func isValidData(_ result: Result<Any>, completion: @escaping (_ : NSDictionary?, _ : Bool?, _ : NSError?) -> Void) {
        self.getValidDict(result, completion: {(dict, error) in
            var success = false
            var errorNew = error
            if dict != nil {
                success = ((dict?["dataKey"] as AnyObject).boolValue)!

                if !success {
                    errorNew = NSError(domain: "", code: 400, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: dict?.value(forKey: "messageKey")! as Any])
                }
            }
            completion (dict, success, errorNew)
        })
    }

    func getValidDict(_ result: Result<Any>, completion: @escaping (_ : NSDictionary?, _ : NSError?) -> Void) {
        var dict: NSDictionary!
        let errorNew = result.error as NSError?
        if let json = result.value {
            dict = (json as AnyObject).value(forKey: "responseKey") as! NSDictionary
        }
        completion (dict, errorNew)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Alamofire to upload image to server.

Try this code:

```
func uploadImage {

    uploadImage(image: image, completion: { (success, error) in
                    if success! {

                    } else {

                    }
                })
}               


    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage!, completion: @escaping (_ : Bool?, _: NSError?) -> Void) {

        let parameters: Parameters = ["image": image]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {
            multipartFormData in

            // For Image
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                if value != nil {
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value!, 0.5) {
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: key, fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                    }
                }
            }
        }, to: "apiName", method: .post, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.response {
                    [weak self] response in
                    guard self != nil
                        else {
                            return
                    }

                    upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

                        self?.isValidData(response.result, completion: {(dict, success, error) in
                            completion (success, error)
                        })
                    })
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error:\(encodingError)")
                completion (false, encodingError as NSError?)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very useful, I appreciate it a lot! :D

Comment: I have a question, where do you declare isValidData? Because in my code is complaining about that, telling me that my class doesn't have a member under that name.

Comment: I have added a new code that will help you to remove your all errors.